# Unable to enter eOS after restoring snapshot in TimeShift

Tags: boot, grub

After restoring a snapshot from TimeShift my laptop reboots and boots onto a blue screen that reads "ERROR: Verification failed:(0x1A)Security Violation".

I have to go into my BIOS setup and disable secure boot for eOS to run. How can I restore snapshots from timeshift without having to disable secure boot?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the SECURE BOOT BIOS which you are using ... you need to set a new value for the  restored partitions which currently dont pass the verifiction of your secure boot.